# Android - Canvas not drawing after Translation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am working on a custom view where i draw lines horizontally one after another left to right. When the collective width of all the lines combined crosses the width of the view , i translate the view. After translating the view , the view moves leftward , but canvas.drawLine stops drawing lines as soon as i translate the view. Any solution to this problem?

```
       for(someCondition){

        canvas?.drawLine(startX,startY,stopX,stopY,linePaint)

        if(startX > (width)){
            log("Invisible , setting translation to ${-(startX - width)}")
            translationX = -(startX - width)
        }

        log("width is $width and startX is $startX")

       }
```

as soon as i translate , the canvas stops drawing but translate keeps happening.

Comment: Translating the canvas does not move the view leftwards.

Comment: Yes i want to move the view so that i can show new lines which are appearing on the right side and hide the old lines which are on the left side.

Comment: If i translate it by -500 , it will be completly invisible but i keep adding new lines and that should increase the width of the view. The lines added on the right should now be appearing on the screen. The question is why arent they appearing?

Comment: Translating the canvas is not showing the new lines.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem without having to translate anything.

Everytime the collective width of the lines crossed the width of the View , i increased the starting index of the array so that i drew only n elements, where n is the max number of lines that can fit inside the views width. This solution also helped avoid drawing unnecessary lines everytime a new element was added to the array.